# Android Custom Background Causing Number Format Exception with List Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

So I'm getting some strange behavior with one of my Android apps.  I have two apps, both with the same custom background image, and one works just fine.  The other, however, does not want to cooperate.

I add a custom theme in my AndroidManifest.xml via the following:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

I change my styles.xml (the entire file) to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dummy_background_image</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Again, this works just fine for app #1.  But app #2...

When I call this:

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Game>(getActivity(),
                                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                                                  android.R.id.text1,
                                                  gameCategories.getCategories()));
```

It throws:

```
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/dummy_background_image.png"
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.view.animation.Animation.<init>(Animation.java:251)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation.<init>(AlphaAnimation.java:40)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:117)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:92)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:73)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:290)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:186)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.example.legacy.GameListFragment.updateListAdapter(GameListFragment.java:107)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.example.legacy.GameListActivity.updateListAdapter(GameListActivity.java:158)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.example.legacy.databaseAccess.DatabaseAccessTask.onPostExecute(DatabaseAccessTask.java:57)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.example.legacy.databaseAccess.DatabaseAccessTask.onPostExecute(DatabaseAccessTask.java:1)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-22 21:30:21.439: E/AndroidRuntime(28044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I go through debug mode, the app does display the app briefly (before it gets to the list adapter) so it can at least find the file.

Obviously, I get that it's a string, and casting it to an int is going to fail.  But why is this casting it to an int and not getting the corresponding number?  Why does it work for app #1 and app #2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: Sure, I can do that when I'm back at that computer.  I'm not sure what you're looking for, however - that's the exception being thrown, and I pasted the line that the stack trace points to.

I'll do it anyways, of course, I just don't know what information you're using to debug the problem, and I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: @StinePike Also, I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to the XML posted.  When I revert back to the XML I had previously (just the default generated XML) the problem goes away.

Comment: ok, Actually Previously I found similar problems in other posts where there were other exceptions behind the scene. that's why asked to show the post ... but here not sure why this is happening ? :(

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the animation. as mine app force closes when executing mProgressContainer.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));

Comment: Yep, it fails in the Alpha animation when trying to get the background color (android.view.animation.Animation.java) line 246: setBackgroundColor(a.getInt(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Animation_background, 0));

Comment: Finally found a solution for it YAY!. The problem is with the background tag in theme, should be windowBackground instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/dummy_background_image</item>
```

instead, use

```
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dummy_background_image</item>
```

and it will work

Comment: Happened to me while testing the migration from Android P to Q

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error trying to set the background image using a custom theme as you have described above. In my case, I wasn't calling setListAdaptor, but instead the same exception was thrown when I switched focus from one input field to another. Also, it was only happening on Android 4.3, not 4.4. I'm not sure why it's not working since it seemed like one of the recommended ways of doing this, but my workaround was to just set the background programatically instead. I stopped getting the error when I removed the "item" tag from the styles.xml file, and added this in my Activity (I happened to need to set the background for a webview).

```
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

Comment: This eventually worked, and was along the right idea.

I had to use:

`gameListFragment.getView().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dummy_background_image));`

If you want to update it to provide the right values, I'll give you answer credit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **android:background** use **android:windowBackground**...this works for me..